# Assembling sending multi-part file POST in Python Socket error

Tags: python, http, sockets, web, post

I have problem.

I want to build an upload server with Python socket scripts.

All the data is transfered to the server one by one succesfully. I concatenate them to become one in a variabel and then after that I save them as one file to my folder. But after that, I can't play it on my windows media player (WMP says there is an error occured).

Indeed, the total file size is not the same as the original file size and also when I compare each segmented data sent and received in server with the suppose segment on the original file is always not the same.

This error is especially happen with multi-part file not with single-part file. The code works fine with single-part file.

What is the problem?

I know that uploading process of a multi-part is use a packet with POST method and then followed by lots of packets that contain the segmented datas sent from the client to the server with incremented SEQ #.

Hence, I don't do conn.close() the clients' connection after 1 POST packet. I conn.close() clients' connection only until all the segmented data finished transfered to the server.

And here is my code folks:

```
import socket
import sys
import base64
import os

HOST = '192.168.43.157'  
PORT = 80
opensession = 0
temp_file = bytes('','utf-8')
filename=""
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
content_length = 0
print('# Socket created')
tot_len_data = 0
tot_post_data = ""
h  = open(r"C:/Users/Totz Tech/Videos/Recording.avi",'rb')
hr = h.read()
h.close()
#s.settimeout(5)
#s.setblocking(False)
# Create socket on port


def getfilename(line):
    seperated_line = line.split("\r\n\r\n")
    seperated_line_1_splitted = seperated_line[1].split("\r\n")
    for i in seperated_line_1_splitted:
        if i.find("Disposition") > -1:
            indeks1 = i.find("filename=")
            indeks2 = i[indeks1+len('filename="')].find('"')
            filename= i[indeks1+len('filename="'):indeks2]
            return filename

def getcontentlength(line):
    seperated_line = line.split("\r\n\r\n")
    seperated_line_1_splitted = seperated_line[1].split("\r\n")
    for i in seperated_line_1_splitted:
        if i.find("Content-length") > -1:
            indeks1 = i.find("=")
            content_length = i[indeks1:]
            return content_length
            

def writepostdata(filename,mode,data):
    f = open(r"C:/Users/Totz Tech/Videos/darinetwork"+filename, mode)
    f.write(bytes(data,'utf-8'))
    f.close()
    
    

try:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error as msg:
    print('# Bind failed. ')
    sys.exit()

print('# Socket bind complete')

# Start listening on socket
s.listen(10)
print('# Socket now listening')

# Wait for client
#conn, addr = s.accept()
#print('# Connected to ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1]))
response = open(r"C:\Users\Totz Tech\Videos\response.txt",'rb').read()
post_still = 0

pack_numb = 1
# Receive data from client
while True:
    print("#######################################")
     
    print("Packet nomor",pack_numb)
    pack_numb = pack_numb + 1
    if post_still == 0:
        conn, addr = s.accept()
    print ("This is the client address: " , addr[0])
    data = conn.recv(317498)
    print("This is snapshot data", data[0:10])
    line = data.decode('UTF-8','ignore') # convert to string (Python 3 only)
    print( "This is data: ", line ) 
    line_member = line.split("\r\n")   # remove newline character
    #1. Get request line
    line_member_0 = line_member[0]
    #2. Get the method
    line_member_0_split = line_member_0.split(" ")
    print("this is the request method: "  + line_member_0_split[0]+". Thank you!")
    #2.1 If the method is get, then:
    if line_member_0_split[0] == "GET":
        try:
            #test the correctness of the client-request
            #check if the 
            line_member_0_split[1][1:] == ""
        except:
            print("Can't serve the client-request")
        else:
            #If the client-request is correct
            if line_member_0_split[1][1:] == "":
                #Because no page information in the client request, then we send our intended index page mypage.html"
                data_to_send = r"C:/Users/Totz Tech/Videos/mypage.html"
                #data_to_send = r"C:\wamp64\www\index.html"
                f1 = open(data_to_send,'rb') 
                conn.send(b'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n'+f1.read())
                print("sent")
                f1.close()
            else:
                token = line_member_0_split[1][1:]
                file_ext = token.split(".")[1]
                data_to_send = "C:/Users/Totz Tech/Videos/"+token
                f1 = open(data_to_send,'rb')
                if file_ext == "jpg":
                    conn.send(b'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nConnection= keep-alive\r\nAccept-Ranges= bytes\r\nContent-Length = 4733\r\nContent-Type= image/jpg\r\n\r\n'+f1.read())
                elif file_ext == "html":
                    conn.send(b'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type = application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n'+f1.read())
                elif file_ext == "mp4":
                    conn.send(b'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type = application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n'+f1.read())
                    #conn.send(b'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type = audio/mp4\r\n\r\n'+f1.read())
                print("SENT")
                f1.close()
                conn.close()
                    
    #2.2 If The method is POST, then:
    elif line_member_0_split[0] == "POST":
        print("Masuk sini")
    
        for i in line_member:
            indeksA1 = i.find("Content-Type:")
            indeksB1 = i.find("boundary") 
            if indeksA1 > -1 and indeksB1 > -1:
                data_delimeter = i[indeksB1+len("boundary="):]
                part_type = i[indeksA1+len("Content-Type:"):indeksB1]
                print("This is data_delimeter: " +data_delimeter)
                print("This is part type: " + part_type)
                print("This is data length: " + str(len(data)))


                

                print("This is data enter / income: ", line)

                try:
                    post_data = line.split(data_delimeter)[2].split("\r\n\r\n")[1]
                    indeks_post_data = line.find(post_data)
                    
                    
                    print("This is post_data from the incomed data: ", post_data)
                except:
                    print("Post no data")
                else:
                    print("This is accumulated storage data before updated: ", tot_post_data)
                    print("This is size of accumulated storage data before updated: ", tot_len_data)

                    if tot_post_data.find(post_data) > -1:
                        print("Data duplicated")
                        tot_post_data = tot_post_data + post_data
                        print("This is accumulated storage data after updated: ", tot_post_data)
                        if data[0:indeks_post_data-1] == hr[0:indeks_post_data-1]:
                            print("Post data included in the original file.")
                            print("ini isi post data", bytes(post_data,'utf-8'),'ini isi hr: ', hr[0:10])
                        else:
                            print("Post data not included in the original file")
                            print("ini isi post data", bytes(post_data,'utf-8'),'ini isi hr: ', hr[0:10])

                    else:
                        print("Data not duplicate")
                        tot_post_data = tot_post_data + post_data
                        print("This is accumulated storage data after updated: ", tot_post_data)
                        if data[0:indeks_post_data-1] == hr[0:indeks_post_data-1]:
                            print("Post data included in the original file.")
                            print("ini isi post data", bytes(post_data,'utf-8')[0:len(post_data.encode('utf-8'))-1],'ini isi hr: ', hr[0:len(post_data.encode('utf-8'))-1])
                        else:
                            print("Post data not included in the original file")
                            print("ini isi post data", bytes(post_data,'utf-8')[0:len(post_data.encode('utf-8'))-1],'ini isi hr: ', hr[0:len(post_data.encode('utf-8'))-1])


                    tot_len_data = len(tot_post_data)
                    print("This is size of accumulated storage data after updated: " , tot_len_data)

                    if tot_len_data > 317298:
                        post_still = 0
                        conn.close()
                    else:
                        post_still = 1
                
                #print("This is total data: " , tot_len_data)

    else:
        if data != b"":

            print("This is data enter / income: ", data)
            #line = hex decoded with utf-8
            post_data = line
            print("This is post_data from the incomed data: ", post_data)


            print("This is accumulated storage data before updated: ", tot_post_data)
                  

            if tot_post_data.find(post_data) > -1:
                print("Data duplicated")
                tot_post_data = tot_post_data + post_data
                print("This is accumulated storage data after updated: ", tot_post_data)
                
                if data[0:indeks_post_data-1] == hr[0:indeks_post_data-1]:
                    print("Post data included in the original file.")
                    print("ini isi post data", bytes(post_data,'utf-8')[0:len(post_data.encode('utf-8'))-1],'ini isi hr: ', hr[0:len(post_data.encode('utf-8'))-1])
                else:
                    print("Post data not included in the original file")
                    print("ini isi post data", bytes(post_data,'utf-8'),'ini isi hr: ', hr[0:10])
            else: 
                print("Data not duplicate")
                tot_post_data = tot_post_data + post_data
                print("This is accumulated storage data after updated: ", tot_post_data)
                if data[0:indeks_post_data-1] == hr[0:indeks_post_data-1]:
                    print("Post data included in the original file.")
                    print("ini isi post data", bytes(post_data,'utf-8')[0:len(post_data.encode('utf-8'))-1],'ini isi hr: ', hr[0:len(post_data.encode('utf-8'))-1])
                else:
                    print("Post data not included in the original file")
                    print("ini isi post data", bytes(post_data,'utf-8'),'ini isi hr: ', hr[0:len(post_data.encode('utf-8'))-1])

            tot_len_data = len(tot_post_data)
            print("This is size of accumulated storage data after updated: " , tot_len_data)
            
            if tot_len_data > 317298  : 
                post_still = 0
                conn.close()
            else:
                indeks_del_akhir = tot_post_data.find(data_delimeter)
                print("Ini indeks delimeter akhir", indeks_del_akhir)
                tot_post_data = tot_post_data[0:indeks_del_akhir-1]
                print("Ini total post data setelah di cut delimeter: ", tot_post_data)
                f = open("C:/Users/Totz Tech/Videos/daripython"+filename+".mp4",'wb')
                f.write(tot_post_data.encode('utf-8'))
                f.close()
                
                post_still = 0
                conn.close()
            
        else:
            post_still = 0
            conn.close()
                

    input("Lanjut?")
                #conn.close()
                #s.send(b"Next")

                
                #line_based_on_data_delimeter = line.split(data_delimeter)
##                post_data = line.split("\r\n\r\n")[2]
##                filename = getfilename(line)
##                content_length = getcontentlength(line)
##
##                if part_type != "multipart/form-data" :
##                    writepostdata(filename, 'wb', post_data)
##                    conn.close()
##                else:
##                    post_data_tot = post_data_tot + post_data
##                    if post_data_tot < content_length:
##                            writepostdata(filename, 'wb', post_data)
##                            conn.close()
```